# How do you serve "normal" static files alongside SPA static files in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application which serves an Angular frontend using ASP.NET's built-in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices`.

In addition to the SPA frontend, which is served from the appropriate directory, I also want to make available a directory (and the static files contained within) through the browser.

I have tried simply configuring the call to `UseStaticFiles` (which is called by default in a `dotnet new <SPA>` invocation) with a `FileProvider` and a `RequestPath`. The application has no trouble locating the directory, but when browsing to the path assigned to that directory directly, I get redirected to the SPA at its root.

EDIT: Once I addressed this issue, I was presented with another issue that prevents this question from being completely answered.

Using `UseFileServer` does not appear to recurse through the directory provided by the `PhysicalFileProvider` (Yes, the directory structure is correct):

[image: No access to subdirectories of the file provider.]
[image: Directory Structure.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "canonical" way to do this appears to be to call `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseDefaultFiles`[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.defaultfilesextensions.usedefaultfiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0) paired with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseStaticFiles`[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileextensions.usestaticfiles?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

As long as these sit *before* the `UseSpaStaticFiles` middleware, ASP.NET will check your static files first before serving the SPA application. Example:

```
var docsFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("doc/site");
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
    FileProvider = docsFileProvider,
    RequestPath = "/docs",

    DefaultFileNames = new[] { "index.html" },
});

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = docsFileProvider, 
    RequestPath = "/docs"
});

var clientAppFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("ClientApp/dist");

if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{
        FileProvider = clientAppFileProvider,
    });
}
```

The problem demonstrated in the edit is caused by the behavior of sending the index of the SPA to the client in the case of a 404. As a result, all the responses for the resources were the SPA's `index.html` file, leading to the displayed issue.

This can be fixed by properly declaring the `RequestPath` in both `UseDefaultFiles` and `UseStaticFiles`.